# Wrong representation of custom account

Tags: android, contacts, account

I have created my own account type, like it's described [here](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/). Everything works fine on emulator or on my LG GT-540 with standard android contacts application. In Contacts application I can see proper custom contact while editing:

[image]

But when my colleague tried this app with HTC device (with its own contacts-management application), he saw the string "company_name.program_name.android.profile" (i.e. android:accountType) instead of "GeneDroid Profile" (i.e. android:label) of my xml/account-authenticator.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:accountType="com.companyname.proframname.account"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
 android:smallIcon="@drawable/geni_logo"
 android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"/>
```

[image]

I cannot understand why it happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like it's using the accountType instead of the label.  I don't think it's anything you're doing wrong.  My only suggestion would be to make that something that would look nice as well.  Unfortunately you need to use it as a key as well so you can't translate it.

Comment: @CaseyB, thanks... I noticed this too. Sam Steele said, that problem on HTC contacts app side.

Comment: For the future you should use black boxes to blank out sensitive information in pictures instead of blur - blur is reversible.

Comment: AndrewKS, thank you I'll use black boxes next time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's using the accountType instead of the label. I don't think it's anything you're doing wrong. My only suggestion would be to make that something that would look nice as well. Unfortunately you need to use it as a key as well so you can't translate it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an correct answer. I saw that this contact app shows ContactType instead of ContactLabel.